# Multiple by 2 until specific number becomes and answer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a logic to build as mentioned below.

```
DECLARE @No INT = 623
DECLARE @Multiple INT  = 100
```

The answer should be the closest floor value multiple to `@No` by multiplying the `@Multiple` by 2

For the above scenario answer should be 600

Scenario 2

```
DECLARE @No INT = 23
DECLARE @Multiple INT  = 5
```

answer should be : 20

Can someone help me with the above logic

Comment: for 23, 25 is the closest than 20

Comment: @Sankar , Sorry. It should be closest floor value. I updated the question.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by `closest floor value` ? A floor value is the largest integer value that is smaller or equal of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : both @No & @Multiple should be integer for this to work

```
select  @No / @Multiple * @Multiple
```